# MySQL dbCursor not working

Tags: mysql, database

Here's my code. I am trying to move cart items into the order items table. What could be possibly wrong its not working?

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `insert_order_details`
(IN `customer_id` VARCHAR(255), 
 IN `order_id` VARCHAR(255), 
 IN `shipping_country` VARCHAR(255), 
 IN `shipping_state` VARCHAR(255), 
 IN `shipping_address` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE product_id  varchar(255);
DECLARE quantity integer;
DECLARE unit_price  integer;

Declare cart_cursor CURSOR 
FOR select @order_id, product_id , quantity, unit_price, userID 
from cart where userID=@customer_id and status = 'PENDING';

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
OPEN cart_cursor;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cart_cursor INTO order_id, product_id, quantity, unit_price, customer_id;

    IF v_finished = 1  THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
      INSERT INTO order_details 
        (order_id,product_id, quantity, unit_price, 
         customer_id,shipping_country,shippping_state, shipping_address)  
      VALUES 
        (@order_id,product_id, quantity, unit_price, @customer_id, 
        date_added,@shipping_country,@shipping_state,@shipping_address) ;

  END LOOP read_loop;

  CLOSE cart_cursor;
END
```

Comment: you can simply do that with an `insert ...select`

Comment: "Its not working" is not a helpful problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to user variable @order_id in your cursor, while you actually want to use a stored procedure variable order_id instead.